# Unit Testing angular HttpInterceptor retry

Tags: angular, unit-testing

this is the first project where I'm trying to have unit test working for angular, so I'm just figuring out how this exactly works. the project is in angular 7 and I have an HttpInteceptorService to retry 2 extra times if an HTTP request fails:

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor() { }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpSentEvent | HttpHeaderResponse | HttpProgressEvent | HttpResponse<any> | HttpUserEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(request).pipe(retry(2));
    }
}
```

my tests for this interceptor so far:

```
describe('HttpInterceptorService', () => {
    beforeEach(() => TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [
            HttpClientTestingModule
        ],
        providers: [
            HttpInterceptorService,
            {
                provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
                useClass: HttpInterceptorService,
                multi: true
            }
        ]
    }));

    it('should be created', () => {
        const service: HttpInterceptorService = TestBed.get(HttpInterceptorService);
        expect(service).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it('should get http 404', () => {
        const http: HttpClient = TestBed.get(HttpClient);

        http.get('/fake-route').subscribe((response: any) => {
            expect(response).toBeTruthy();
            expect(response.status).toEqual('404');
        });
    });
});
```

so I'm testing if i get a 404 successfully but I have no idea how to test if the interceptor is repeating the 2 extra times.

**Edit**

Actualy I was wrong, not even my `'should get http 404'` test is working correctly, it's just always giving a false positive.

**Edit 2**

I believe I'm getting closer, the 404 is now working properly and I've added a test for the "retrying" but it's still not working as expected I think the interceptor is probably not even being called...

```
it('should repeat failed request 2 more times', () => {
    const emsg = 'deliberate 404 error';

    jasmine.clock().install();
    spyOn(httpClient, 'get').and.callThrough();

    expect(httpClient.get).not.toHaveBeenCalled();

    httpClient.get(fakeUrl).subscribe(
    (response) => {
      fail('should have failed with the 404 error');
    },
    (error) => {
      expect(error.status).toEqual(404, 'status');
      expect(error.error).toEqual(emsg, 'message');
    });

    jasmine.clock().tick(3000);

    expect(httpClient.get).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(3);

    jasmine.clock().uninstall();
});
```

and this test fails with "Expected spy get to have been called 3 times. It was called 1 times"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, finally figured it out, my latest approach (Edit 2) was not the right one either. Here's my final and working test for the repeating:

```
it('should handle 404 with retry (2 times)', () => {
    const emsg = 'deliberate 404 error';

    httpClient.get(fakeUrl).subscribe(
    (response) => {
        fail('should have failed with the 404 error');
    },
    (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        expect(error.status).toEqual(404, 'status');
        expect(error.error).toEqual(emsg, 'message');
    });

    const retry = 2;
    for (let i = 0, c = retry + 1; i < c; i++) {
        const req = httpTestingController.expectOne(fakeUrl);
        req.flush(emsg, { status: 404, statusText: 'Not Found' });
    }
});
```

also added an assert to run after every test to make sure that there are no more pending requests:

```
afterEach(() => {
    httpTestingController.verify();
});
```